# Is there another way to add multiple tags in a HTML form before submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I have an Admin panel for my custom Knowledgebase written using HTML, JQuery and PHP that reads an XML file and allows for adding more records to the file through a HTML form. The page sends the new record and then gets updated via AJAX. The XML records represent Knowledgebase articles and I have just recently added tags to these records for better searching and categorisation.

The problem I have is in finding another way to handle adding multiple tags to the HTML form for a new record before inserting. I am not looking for an opinion on the "best" way to do this rather I am looking for knowledge I may not possess on different functionality supported either by HTML, JQuery or PHP that will allow me to achieve the goal of adding multiple tags before submitting the form.

I have three goals: **1)** to be able to choose a tag, add it to a list in the form and then add more if needed before submitting and **2)** to be able to display the selected tags in a readable, scrollable manner and lastly **3)** if possible, to do this without having to programatically add (and then read from) multiple input fields.

I know that I could add an **input type=text**, a **select** input and a **button** and use JavaScript to populate the text input with strings filled with the selected tags and delimit the entire string with a known safe character to separate each tag. I could then pass this input field through my AJAX query and process the string in the PHP file being called by AJAX. This just seems like the wrong way to go about this. Additionally this doesn't fulfil **Goal (2)**.

I also know I could use the **select** input with **multiple** but this fails **Goal (2)** also and when I have a list of 100 tags, and I need to add 15 of them at various places in the list it becomes counterproductive.

Is there another way to do all of this? Again, not looking for an opinion on the "best" way to do this or even an opinion in the first place, just for knowledge, corrections or tips I may not be aware of that will achieve what I'm looking for.

I have included my JQuery code, my HTML/PHP for the form and a sample of my XML file below.

JQuery:

```js
$('#submit_add').click(function(){
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var articleId = $("#id").val();
    var articleTitle = $("#title").val();
    var articleFilepath = $("#filepath").val();
    var articleLevel = $("#level").val();
    var ajaxurl = 'kb_add_article.php',
    data =  {'action': clickBtnValue, 'id': articleId, 'title': articleTitle, 'filepath': articleFilepath, 'level': articleLevel};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        // Response div goes here.
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```php
//display a form
echo "<div id='add_article'>";
    echo "<form class='form-signin' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr><td colspan='2'>Add a New Article</td></tr>
                <tr><td>ID:</td><td><input id='id' name='id' type='text' value='", ($highest_id + 1), "' disabled></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Title:</td><td><input id='title' name='title' type='text'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>File Path:</td><td><input id='filepath' name='filepath' type='text'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Level:</td><td><select id='level' name='level'>
                            <option value='1'>1st Line</option>
                            <option value='2'>2nd Line</option>
                        </select></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' class='button button1' id='submit_add' value='insert'></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>";
echo "</div>";
```

XML:

```xml
<article>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Claims Test</title>
    <filepath>Claims.md</filepath>
    <level>1</level>
    <category>dispensary</category>
    <tags>
        <tag>product:rx</tag>
        <tag>product:rx-365</tag>
    </tags>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript to add multiple inputs, but use square brackets in the name like so `<input name="someName[]" />`.

Then in your PHP, you can use `$_POST['someName']`, and it will contain an array of values for all of the inputs that had the name `someName[]`.